# Community♦ raised flag for 20+ comments even though most of them are deleted

Tags: feature-request, comments, moderator-tools, community-user, automatic-flags

2 comments left.

> [image]

But Community♦ raised flag to move comments ('cause there are 20+) to chat.

> [image]

I guess, only not deleted comments should be counted.

Comment: Time to give Community a flag ban.